# rint not present in Visual Studio 2010 math.h and equivalent of CUDA rint

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda

I'm porting a CUDA code to C++ and using Visual Studio 2010. The CUDA code uses the `rint` function, which does not seem to be present in the Visual Studio 2010 math.h, so it seems that I need to implement it by myself.

According to this [link](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE_g3b8026edb2f2e441669845f0f3fa3bf7.html), the CUDA `rint` function

*rounds x to the nearest integer value in floating-point format, with halfway cases rounded towards zero.*

I think I could use the casting to `int` which discards the fractional part, effectively rounding towards zero, so I ended-up with the following function

```
inline double rint(double x)
{
    int temp; temp = (x >= 0. ? (int)(x + 0.5) : (int)(x - 0.5));
    return (double)temp;
}
```

which has two different castings, one to `int` and one to `double`.

I have three questions:

1. Is the above function fully equivalent to CUDA `rint` for "small" numbers? Will it fail for "large" numbers that cannot be represented as an `int`?
2. Is there any more computationlly efficient way (rather than using two castings) of defining `rint`?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I doubt you need casting to int, and it's error-prone anyway. Use floor/ceil instead?

Comment: Your question has already been answered and njuffa's answer is probably the nicest possible `rint()` implementation, but I should point out that there are more issues with the `+ 0.5` version than just the overflow for `double` arguments that cannot be represented as `int`. With a strict IEEE 754 compiler, the answers for 0.49999999999999994 and for half the numbers between 2^52 and 2^53 are incorrect. Please see http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/02/nearbyintf1 (for `float`, explanations easily translatable to `double`).

Comment: The above implementation will fail for numbers bigger than 2^31 if int is 32-bit on your computer. Use of int64_t instead of int will help somewhat, but still have problems when x is a large double (greater than 2^63).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The cited description of rint() in the CUDA documentation is incorrect. Roundings to integer with floating-point result map the IEEE-754 (2008) specified rounding modes as follows:

```
trunc()   // round towards zero
floor()   // round down (towards negative infinity)
ceil()    // round up (towards positive infinity)
rint()    // round to nearest or even (i.e. ties are rounded to even)
round()   // round to nearest, ties away from zero
```

Generally, these functions work as described in the C99 standard. For rint(), the standard specifies that the function rounds according to the current rounding mode (which defaults to round to nearest or even). Since CUDA does not support dynamic rounding modes, all functions that are defined to use the current rounding mode use the rounding mode "round to nearest or even". Here are some examples showing the difference between round() and rint():

```
argument  rint()  round()
1.5       2.0     2.0
2.5       2.0     3.0
3.5       4.0     4.0
4.5       4.0     5.0
```

round() can be emulated fairly easily along the lines of the code you posted, I am not aware of a simple emulation for rint(). Please note that you would not want to use an intermediate cast to integer, as 'int' supports a narrower numeric range than integers that are exactly representable by a 'double'. Instead use trunc(), ceil(), floor() as appropriate.

Since rint() is part of both the current C and C++ standards, I am a bit surprised that MSVC does not include this function; I would suggest checking MSDN to see whether a substitute is offered. If your platforms are SSE4 capable, you could use the SSE intrinsics `_mm_round_sd(), _mm_round_pd()` defined in `smmintrin.h`, with the rounding mode set to `_MM_FROUND_TO_NEAREST_INT`, to implement the functionality of CUDA's rint().

While (in my experience), the SSE intrinsics are portable across Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X, you may want to avoid hardware specific code. In this case, you could try the following code (lightly tested):

```
double my_rint(double a)
{
    const double two_to_52 = 4.5035996273704960e+15;
    double fa = fabs(a);
    double r = two_to_52 + fa;
    if (fa >= two_to_52) {
        r = a;
    } else {
        r = r - two_to_52;
        r = _copysign(r, a);
    }
    return r;
}
```

Note that MSVC 2010 seems to lack the standard copysign() function as well, so I had to substitute _copysign(). The above code assumes that the current rounding mode is round-to-nearest-even (which it is by default). By adding 2**52 it makes sure that rounding occurs at the integer unit bit. Note that this also assumes that pure double-precision computation is performed. On platforms that use some higher precision for intermediate results one might need to declare 'fa' and 'r' as volatile.

Comment: Thanks njuffa. Competent and precise answer as always! I was also surprised that Visual Studio 2010 does not support `rint`, but this [post](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t532986-rounding-functions-in-microsoft-visual-c-c.html) seems to support this. I have tested your `my_rint` code and works correctly. Should a bug report be filed to fix the CUDA documentation?

Comment: I have already filed a bug to get the CUDA documentation fixed with respect to rint().